# Water dripping from handheld shower head loop

Tags: pressure, temperature, water

I've got a shower head attached to the wall by a long metal covered flexible hose. The shower head stays attached to the wall so there is a long loop of hose hanging down between the wall and the actual shower head. When I turn the water off, the flow immediately stops. After a minute or two the water that was in the loop will start dripping out of the shower head on it's own fairly quickly. There's no leaking valve, so it's not new water pushing out the old. Any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

This question has also been asked [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/20111). It is most likely residual water in the shower head.

After running the shower, a fair amount of water is still left in the shower head but it doesn't immediately flow out due to the small nozzles and surface tension, just like how inverting a small bottle of water keeps the water inside as there is no place for air to enter.

However, the nozzles are not all evenly covered with water. As the system cools and dries out, eventually one of them will open up and allow air in, resulting in a sudden outflow. In my experience, this can even happen many hours after the shower is used.

Answer (score 0):

> Once the shower is turned off and the shower diverter lever is pushed down, excess water in the vertical shower standpipe (inside the wall) falls backward so most of the water drains into the tub through the tub spout. During this process, an airlock develops in the standpipe, trapping water in the horizontal portion of the shower arm and also in the showerhead.
>
> Inside the showerhead near the back is a flow restrictor which may restrict air entering the system, air that would normally help to completely flush out the water once the shower diverter lever is pushed down.

From [Plumbing And Showers](http://www.asktooltalk.com/questions/faq/plumbing/bathtubs_showers/showerheads.php)

Comment: How would trapped hot water push it out?  If it's allowed to cool down for a few minutes I wouldn't expect that.

Comment: @JMac. Spot on, the dripping in my shower drives me crazy, but it is half physics, half engineering in my opinion. No, actually  it's mostly engineering, in my opinion, it varies from shower to shower, I would bet.

Comment: We have 2 showers and they both work differently. One works the way it was described in this post, and other one works with just a  thumb shutoff value - it dripped all the time. We had to replace the thumb shutoff  with a straight value quarter turn shut-off.